# Extract path information from an black&white bitmap image

Tags: ios, quartz-2d, bitmapimage, cgpath

It is not easy to draw a shape with `Quartz 2D` to depict an image as following. Is it possible to extract a `CGPathRef` information from a black&white bitmap image? The white part is actually transparent.

[image: a black&white bitmap image]

**Edit**:

What I want to achieve:

I want to set the `physicsBody` of a `SKSpriteNode` with the same shape of the image `bottle.png`

```
SKSpriteNode * myBottle = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bottle"];
.
.
.
myBottle.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath:path];
```

Her `path` is a `CGPathRef`, I wanna to make it have the same shape with the image `bottle.png`

Comment: What you want to achieve by that path reference?

Comment: @PoojaManiklalBohora I have edit the question, plz check:)

Answer (score 0):

Google potrace
It's one of several open source libraries that do this. 
It also handily links to others.