# SKSpriteNode with an image: Get CGPath of outline

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

Is it possible to extract the CGPath of an transparent image inside of an SKSpriteNode?
I need the information for .physicsBody and for drawing shadows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extract path information from an black&white bitmap image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22654401/extract-path-information-from-an-blackwhite-bitmap-image)

Comment: in ios 8 you can init a body with the outline of an image, check the prerelease docs